# `size` has no method matching size(::Data{Float32}) when using nested composite type in julia

Tags: julia

say I defined a composite type "Data" as follows:

```
type DataFormat
    format1::DataType
    format2::Uint
    format3::Uint
    format4::Ptr{None}
end

type Data{T} <: AbstractVector{T}
    value::Vector{T}
    format::DataFormat    
end
```

It's OK when I run `myformat = DataFormat(Float32, 0, 0, C_NULL)`.
But as I run this `mydata = Data{Float32}([0.1, 0.2, 0.3], myformat)`, these errors appear:

```
Error showing value of type Data{Float32}:
ERROR: `size` has no method matching size(::Data{Float32})
in writemime at replutil.jl:18
in display at REPL.jl:117
in display at REPL.jl:120
in display at multimedia.jl:149
in print_response at REPL.jl:139
in print_response at REPL.jl:124
in anonymous at REPL.jl:586
in run_interface at /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/julia/0.3.7/Julia-      0.3.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
in run_frontend at /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/julia/0.3.7/Julia-0.3.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
in run_repl at /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/julia/0.3.7/Julia-0.3.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
in _start at /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/julia/0.3.7/Julia-0.3.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
```

It seems something broken with julia's size() function, how can I fix it?
I'm very new to julia and don't know whether it's a good choice to use "nested" composite type like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's relatively straightforward to extend `size`:

```
julia> import Base.size

julia> size(d::Data) = size(d.value)
size (generic function with 51 methods)
```

If you want your datatype to support other operations like iteration and indexing you'll need to also define `getindex`, <s>start, next, length and done</s>

Edit: See comment below for why start, next, length and done are not necessary.

Comment: Just `size` and `getindex` are required, with `setindex!` and `similar` if you want mutability.  start/next/length/done (and many other methods) are provided for "free", based upon indexing and the array size.  See: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/arrays/#implementation

Comment: If the OP wanted to do something like `for item in data`, I believe `start`, `next`, and `done` are required.  `length` typically simplifies the definition of `done`

Comment: Yup, but those are already defined for *all* `AbstractArray`s in terms of `size` and `getindex`!  Here's [`length`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a18af0064e05c8240185cc499c5a4e2b044f415d/base/abstractarray.jl#L23), and here are [the iteration definitions](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a18af0064e05c8240185cc499c5a4e2b044f415d/base/abstractarray.jl#L245-L248).  There are lots of generic functions like this — don't write more code than you need to!

Comment: Ah. That's very good to know.  I've updated my answer so it no longer contains lies

Comment: your answers are helpful, I should read more docs about AbstractArray